Rankin-Selberg: Basic series manipulation
In Garrett's Basic Rankin-Selberg notes page 4, he indicated that the following identity holds (formally at least) just by 'summing the geometric series separately'
$$\sum_{l\geq0} X^l \cdot \frac{\alpha^{l+1} - \beta^{l+1}}{\alpha - \beta}\cdot \frac{\gamma^{l+1} - \delta^{l+1}}{\gamma - \delta} = \frac{1}{\alpha - \beta} \cdot \frac{1}{\gamma - \delta}\cdot \left( \frac{\alpha \gamma}{1 - \alpha \gamma X} - \frac{\alpha \delta}{1 - \alpha \delta X} - \frac{\beta \gamma}{1- \beta \gamma X} + \frac{\beta \delta}{1 - \beta \delta X} \right)$$
for $X = p^{-s}$.
May I know what anyone is able to interpret what does 'summing the geometric series separately' mean? Or are there any other ways to attain the above identity?

Your series can be written as a sum of four geometric series (by multiplying out the term).  The first of those series is
$$
\sum_{l \ge 0} \frac{X^l\,\alpha^{l+1}\,\gamma^{l+1}}{(\alpha-\beta)(\gamma-\delta)} ,
$$
and its sum is
$$
\frac{1}{(\alpha-\beta)(\gamma-\delta)}\cdot \frac{\alpha\gamma}{1-\alpha\gamma X} .
$$

Oh I see, thank you for the prompt reply!
